# Работа с файлами для чтения в Python

Tags: python, файлы, поиск, данные

Как обратиться к файлу, чтобы прочитать данные из него и где он должен располагаться, чтобы Пайтон его увидел, а не сообщал, что такого файла вообще не существует? Моя попытка:

```
import f:'meno2'
f = open('meno2')
read.f(20)
for i in range(20):
    write(str(f[i]),' ')
f.close()
```

"Такого файла вообще не существует"! сообщение Python/

Comment: А это что: `import f:'meno2'`?

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы обратиться к файлу и прочитать данные из него в Python, файл должен располагаться в той же директории, откуда запускается ваш скрипт, или вы можете указать полный путь к файлу.

```
import os
file_path = 'file.txt'
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        print('Success')
else:
    print('Failure')
```

Comment: Во-первых, у вас явно что-то с отступами. Во-вторых, конструкция `with-else` сложновата для чтения новичком. В-третьих, если вы уже проверили `os.path.exists`, то никакого `else`, по идее, быть не должно. А если он и будет, то это уже не относится к вопросу.

Comment: @Глеб спасибо, форматирование кода исправил